# Android and IllegalStateException

Tags: android, exception, android-contentprovider, illegalstateexception

Would it be valid for me to throw an `IllegalStateException` in my Android application if I am executing a chunk of code that requires a number of variables not to be null, e.g. in the content provider `delete()` function I have:

```
public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int count;
        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case NOTES:
                count = db.delete(NOTES_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
                break;

            case NOTE_ID:
                String noteId = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                count = db.delete(NOTES_TABLE_NAME, NoteColumns._ID + "=" + noteId
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(where) ? " AND (" + where + ')' : ""), whereArgs);
                break;

            default:
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
       }

       getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
       return count;

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
       // We really shouldn't get any null pointers!
       throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

Because, although highly unlikely, there is a small chance that the following variables could be NULL:

```
- mOpenHelper
- db
- getContext()
- getContentResolver()
```

Or is this an abuse of `IllegalStateException`? The reason I want to do this is because to me it seems wrong for this function to just throw `NullPointerExceptions`?

Comment: Personally I would prefer a NPE with the full stack trace so I know what is causing it. If you want to hide the implementation from the user but still communicate back when something fails, I would actively check for null or invalid params and throw an exception then and there with the invalid param any other useful information you could give.

Comment: so for example, if the caller was an activity: you would put a try{ getContentResolver().delete(myUri, myWhere, myWhereArgs); } catch (NullPointerException e) { // do domething with e }?

Comment: `db`, `getContext()` and `getContentResolver()` can't return `null`, `mOpenHelper` it's a reference to your own class and I don't see how it could be `null` if you properly instantiate it in the provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the minimum, use `throw new IllegalStateException(e);` to keep the information about what caused the exception in the first place.

I would personally make sure that NPE cannot happen by making sure that all the required variables (mOpenHelper etc) are properly initialised before I need to use them.

Comment: I agree - I am trying to make sure a NPE cannot happen. However, I want to add in an explicit check just in case (as you can never say never!).

Comment: @Mewzer I think the next question really is: if you get a NPE, can you recover from it or not? If you can, catch it and recover, if you can't let it bubble up and catch it at the highest level to give an "unexpected error blabla".

Comment: Thanks - in this case if any of those happened to be null, then I guess it would not be possible to recover.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create your own exception?

```
public class MyCustomException extends NullPointerException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Exception innerException;

    public MyCustomException() {}

    public MyCustomException(Exception innerException) {
        this.innerException = innerException;
    }
}

...

if (mOpenHelper == null){thrown new MyCustomException("mOpenHelper is null!");}
```

Or, just catch the NPE, figure out why, then throw up your own.